# агрегированые функции и group by postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

Нужно вывести медиану выборки   и размер выборки. 
медиана- это значение которое находиться по `порядковому номеру = размер/2` округленные в меньшую сторону,

т.е. в этом примере должно быть 33 на месте 7

Нужно вывеси 33/15

вот мой код, который не работает т.к. при использовании агрегирвоанных функций нужно использовать group by

```
CREATE TABLE random(ID INT primary key , Value INT unique )  
INSERT INTO random 
values 
(1,1),
(2,3),
(3,7),
(4,10),
(5,16),
(6,17),
(7,33),
(8,21),
(9,27),
(10,41),
(11,25),
(12,13),
(13,23),
(14,29),
(15,9)

Select  cast count(*) as tatal, value  from random 
where  id =  cast (count(*)/2 as int)
```

можно ли как-то переписать с помощью `group by ?` без `with as и limit`

Comment: Вы предполагаете, что id не имеет пропусков, что не обязательно при работе с реальными данными. Лучше использовать номер строки, т.е. ROW_NUMBER().

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте использовать подзапросы:

```
SELECT
    (select count(*) from random) as total_count,
    value 

FROM
    random
WHERE
    id = (select cast (count(*)/2 as int) from random)
```

**UPD.**

Тогда вместо `id` номер строки

```
SELECT tcount, value FROM
(SELECT
    ROW_NUMBER() over (ORDER BY id) as rnum,
    COUNT(*) over () as tcount,
    value 
FROM random) sq
 WHERE
    sq.rnum = (select cast (count(*)/2 as int) from random)
```

Comment: так не верно т.к. id не обязательно будут идти по порядку

Comment: вчера с другом тоже к такому решению пришли, ток так тоже не верно т.к. ORDER BY id отсортирует значения по id, а нужен такой же порядок сохранить

Comment: тогда вам нужно использовать R